# call a function without leaving out input global variable

Tags: python, global-variables, function-calls

```
CHANGE_TOTAL = (float(input('type in the change total ')))
def main():
    value_1 = (float(input('type in the first value ')))
    value_2 = (float(input('type in the second value ')))
    value_3 = (float(input('type the third value ')))
    values_average(value_1,value_2,value_3)
def values_average(a,b,c):
    total = (a+b+c)
    if total >  CHANGE_TOTAL:
        print ('there\'s not change availibility at the moment plase wait')
        main()
    else:
        print ('your change is being process plase wait a moment')
    change_due(total)
def change_due(items_cost):
    input ('"press enter"')
    money_received = (float(input('type in the amount of money received ')))
    change = (money_received - items_cost)
    print ('your change is', change)
    change_total_aft_trans(change)
def change_total_aft_trans(a):
    change_left = (CHANGE_TOTAL - a)
    print ('the change left is', change_left)

main()
```

this is the thing as you can see in the ¨values_average funtion¨ when i try to loop the whole thing over by calling the ¨main function¨after the if-statement it doesn't asks me to type in a new CHANGE_TOTAL value, which is what i would like to do. any advice ? thanks in advance

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. It is impossible to read Python without correct indentation.

Comment: i meant CHANGE_TOTAL

Comment: Don't post corrections in the comments. *Correct the question itself by editing it*.

Comment: thanks for the advices

Comment: Why does `change_total` have to be a global?

Comment: i don't know because i'm stubborn i guess, though if there's a way to make this work without changing the change_total global nature would be cool

Comment: You should really reconsider the fundamental design of your program. You are using mutual recursion to modify global variables. You should consider a more straightforward design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think relying on mutable global state is *uncool*. But you can easily do it that way, if you really want. Move your `CHANGE_TOTAL = (float(input('type in the change total ')))` *inside* `main` and put a `global` directive:

```
def main():
    global CHANGE_TOTAL
    CHANGE_TOTAL = (float(input('type in the change total ')))
    value_1 = (float(input('type in the first value ')))
    value_2 = (float(input('type in the second value ')))
    value_3 = (float(input('type the third value ')))
    values_average(value_1,value_2,value_3)
def values_average(a,b,c):
    total = (a+b+c)
    if total >  CHANGE_TOTAL:
        print ('there\'s not change availibility at the moment plase wait')
        main()
    else:
        print ('your change is being process plase wait a moment')
    change_due(total)
def change_due(items_cost):
    input ('"press enter"')
    money_received = (float(input('type in the amount of money received ')))
    change = (money_received - items_cost)
    print ('your change is', change)
    change_total_aft_trans(change)
def change_total_aft_trans(a):
    change_left = (CHANGE_TOTAL - a)
    print ('the change left is', change_left)
```

Here would be a more sensible design, in my opinion:

```
def main():
    change_total, *values = prompt_values()
    cost = sum(values)
    while cost > change_total:
        print("there's not change availibility at the moment plase wait")
        change_total, *values = prompt_values()
        cost = sum(values)
    change_due(cost, change_total)

def prompt_values():
    change_total = float(input('type in the change total '))
    value_1 = float(input('type in the first value '))
    value_2 = float(input('type in the second value '))
    value_3 = (float(input('type the third value ')))
    return change_total, value_1, value_2, value_3

def change_due(items_cost, change_total):
    print ('your change is being process plase wait a moment')
    input ('"press enter"')
    money_received = (float(input('type in the amount of money received ')))
    change = (money_received - items_cost)
    print ('your change is', change)
    change_total_aft_trans(change, change_total)

def change_total_aft_trans(change, change_total):
    change_left = change_total - change
    print ('the change left is', change_left)
```

Note, I use a while-loop instead of mutual recursion.

Comment: thanks it works, i will re-think the way i write code either way, i started learning python two weeks ago with a pdf call starting out with python it is a pretty good book so far

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit. It's good practice in programming not to define global variables it they are going to change as it gets nigh impossible in large co debases to track errors. It's best to pass around the value to be changed into a function, then return its new value back. This makes it much code base easier to test individual functions for errors. If you are wanting to return multiple values, just return tuples and unpack, eg

```
def func(val1, val2, val3):
    val1 += 1
    val2 += 2
    val3 += 3 
    return (val1, val2, val3)

def main():
    a, b, c = 1, 2 ,3
    a, b, c = func(a, b, c)
    # a=2, b=4, c=6
```

I have also added a try except block which will make the program stay open if you accidently mistype in a value, this is really good practice.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def main():
    # Insdead of gloval funciton just pass it to functions
    CHANGE_TOTAL = get_value('CHANGE TOTAL')   

    value_1 = get_value('Value1')
    value_2 = get_value('Value2')
    value_3 = get_value('Value3')
    average = values_average(value_1,value_2,value_3)
    new_balance = withdraw(CHANGE_TOTAL, average)

# Since you are getting three float values from input why not make a fucntion
# that gets a values, specifed by a name and checks for invalid entries
# if you ever need to get another float value, just call this with a param
def get_value(name_of_value: str) -> float:
    print('Please enter the',name_of_value, 'value: ', end='')
    while True:
        try:
            value = float(input())
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid entry, try again: ', end='')
    return value

#this functions does too much seperate it fucntions: get_average() and
# withdraw() deposit()

def values_average(a,b,c):
    total = a + b + c 
    return total / 3 #average

def withdraw(available_change, amount):
    if amount >= available_change:
        return available_change - ammount
    else:
        print('Invaild funds for transaction')

"""
# Please note I have stopped here!! b
def change_due(items_cost):
    input ('"press enter"')
    money_received = (float(input('type in the amount of money received ')))
    change = (money_received - items_cost)
    print ('your change is', change)
    change_total_aft_trans(change)

def change_total_aft_trans(a):
    change_left = (CHANGE_TOTAL - a)
    print ('the change left is', change_left)
"""

main()
```